# How to foreachRDD over records from Kafka in Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.6

I'd like to run a Spark Streaming application with Kafka as the data source. It works fine in local but fails in cluster. I'm using spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10.6.

Here are the source code and the stack trace.

**DevMain.scala**

object DevMain extends App with Logging {

```
1.val lme: RawMetricsExtractor = new JsonExtractor[HttpEvent](props, topicArray)

2 val broadcastLme=sc.broadcast(lme)

3.  val lines: DStream[MetricTypes.InputStreamType] = myConsumer.createDefaultStream()  
4.  lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
5.    if ((rdd != null) && (rdd.count() > 0) && (!rdd.isEmpty())) {
6.      logInfo("filteredLines: " + rdd.count())
7.      logInfo("start loop")
8.      val le = broadcastLme.value
        rdd.foreach(x => lme.aParser(x).get)
9.      logInfo("end loop")
10.    }   
11.  }
12. lines.print(10)
```

}
I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at line 6 and the code doesn't enter `lme.parser`.

This is `lme.parser`:

```
class JsonExtractor [T <: SpecificRecordBase : Manifest]
(props:java.util.Properties, topicArray:Array[String])
  extends java.io.Serializable with RawMetricsExtractor with TitaniumConstants with Logging {

    def aParser(x: MetricTypes.InputStreamType): Option[MetricTypes.RawMetricEntryType] = {

      logInfo("jUtils: " + jUtils)
      logInfo("jFactory: " + jsonF)

      if(x == null) {
        logInfo("x is null: " + jUtils)
        return None
      }
}
```

i have log on line1 of `lme.parser` and it does not get printed and it does not enter `lem.parser`.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.7 in stage 11.0 (TID 118, dev-titanium-os-wcdc-spark-4.traxion.xfinity.tv): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DevMain$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DevMain.scala:6)
    at DevMain$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DevMain.scala:6)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:910)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)
    at DevMain$$anonfun$4.apply(DevMain.scala:6)
    at DevMain$$anonfun$4.apply(DevMain.scala:6)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DevMain$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DevMain.scala:6)
    at DevMain$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DevMain.scala:3)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
```

### ... 3 more

this is the new exception after the broadcast variable changes

```
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger logWarning - Exception in serialization debugger
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.DateFormat.hashCode(DateFormat.java:739)
    at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$HashUtils$class.elemHashCode(FlatHashTable.scala:391)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.elemHashCode(HashSet.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.findEntryImpl(FlatHashTable.scala:123)
    at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.containsEntry(FlatHashTable.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.containsEntry(HashSet.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.contains(HashSet.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1326)
    at DevMain$delayedInit$body.apply(DevMain.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at DevMain$.(DevMain.scala:17)
    at DevMain.main(DevMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:558)
[ERROR] 2016-12-26 18:01:23,039 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster logError - User class threw exception: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.modifiers.SetTypeModifier$
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.modifiers.SetTypeModifier$
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1326)
    at .DevMain$delayedInit$body.apply(DevMain.scala:103)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at DevMain$.main(DevMain.scala:17)
    at DevMain.main(DevMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:558)
```

Comment: where `lme` is defined (line#6) ? check `lme.aParser(x).get`, here `lme.aParser(x)` might be null

Comment: yeah `lme.aParser(x).get` is the cause I suppose , because this code will run on worker and you are not broadcasting it and hence it gives null pointer on worker. Try to broadcast this value and then use it accordingly !

Comment: def aParser(x: MetricTypes.InputStreamType): Option[MetricTypes.RawMetricEntryType] = {

    logInfo("jUtils: " + jUtils)
    logInfo("jFactory: " + jsonF)

    if(x == null) {
      logInfo("x is null: " + jUtils)
     return None
    }
}

Comment: this is the lme.aparser .....i have a log ....here on line1 ...that never get's printed ......

Comment: Can you show the code where you define `lme`? `(rdd != null)` and `rdd.count()` are not needed (and the latter triggers a Spark job, i.e. adds up to the execution time and makes your app slightly slower).

Comment: thanks for your comment will surely remove them

Comment: i added the code where lme is defined

Answer (score 1):

Yeah `lme.aParser(x).get` is the cause I suppose , because this code will run on worker and you are not broadcasting `lme` object it and hence it gives **null pointer** on worker.

Try to broadcast this value and then use it accordingly !

Something this would work :

```
val broadcaseLme=sc.broadcast(lme)
val lines: DStream[MetricTypes.InputStreamType] = myConsumer.createDefaultStream()  
             lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
            if ((rdd != null) && (rdd.count() > 0) && (!rdd.isEmpty()) ) {
              logInfo("filteredLines: " + rdd.count())
              logInfo("start loop")
              rdd.foreach{x => 
                 val lme = broadcastLme.value    
                 lme.aParser(x).get
                  }
              logInfo("end loop")
            }   })

          lines.print(10)
```

Comment: How can you know if `lme` can be broadcast? What if it uses non-Serializable objects? Without knowing more about `lme` I'd hardly recommend a broadcast variable.

Comment: Thanks ....Srivastava for pointing me in the right direction ...after adding broadcast variable ...i'm getting serialization errors

Comment: Jacek could you please point me how to overcome the serialization exceptions

Comment: @user2359997: Can you please point out how your lme looks like! is it a serializable object !

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava could you please point how would i pass the broadcast variable if instead of foreachRdd we want to use

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava could you please point how would i pass the broadcast variable if instead of foreachRdd we want to use lines.map(lme.parser)